# COUNT how many times a value appears and divide it by the number of total data

Tags: sql

I need to write an SQL query that count the number of time a certain value appears, but then i need it to divide it by the total number of interventions (different table = dbo.gi3_intervention.gi3_n_intrvt) and multiply it by 100 to get the pourcentage.

I only know how to count the number of time the certain value appear, but I don't know how to do the division.

**EDIT:**

I need to divide it by the number of interventions that are closed since may first 2021. The intervention table is linked to the one stated above.

The intervention table = `dbo.gi3_intervention.gi3_n_intrvt` 
the type should be '08', so `dbo.gi3_intervention.GI3_C_TYPE_INTRVT = '08'`
And should be closed since may 1st 2021, so `dbo_GI3_INTERVENTION.GI3_D_CLOT_INTRVT = '>2021-05-01'`

This is what I got:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site
WHERE dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site.gi3_c_sous_sujt_note = 'Etud tech Renseig add'
```

Comment: We need more info. Like, are the tables linked? How to filter the values on the different table (dbo.gi3_intervention). An example of data and expected result would also be good.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using (which I would guess is SQL Server based on the `dbo`).

Comment: I see you edited the question, but you still did not specify how are the tables linked (by which field). An example is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can use conditional aggregation.  An elegant way (in my opinion) uses `AVG()`:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN nias.gi3_c_sous_sujt_note = 'Etud tech Renseig add' THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END) as percentage_etud
FROM dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site nias
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, but I made a mistake in my question. I edited my question. I need to divide the first number found by the total number of interventions closed since may 1st 2021... If you could help it would be greatly appreciated! thank you.

Comment: @ChNa . . . That substantially changes the question, which was original about about table and how to do a particular calculation.  It is really better to ask a *new* question when a question has been answered.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time. I will ask this question when stackoverflow allows it again in about 60 minutes I guess. Thank you again, hope to see you on my second question!

Comment: Follow up to my first question if interested .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67562485/count-how-many-times-a-value-appears-in-my-interventions-and-divide-it-by-the-nu?noredirect=1#comment119418875_67562485