# COUNT how many times a value appears in my interventions and divide it by the number of total interventions

Tags: sql

I need to write an SQL query that count the number of time a certain value appears, but then i need it to divide it by the total number of interventions and multiply it by 100 to get the pourcentage.

I need to divide it by the number of interventions that are closed since may first 2021. The intervention table is linked to the one stated above.

The intervention table = `dbo.gi3_intervention.gi3_n_intrvt`
the type should be '08', so `dbo.gi3_intervention.GI3_C_TYPE_INTRVT = '08'`
And should be closed since may 1st 2021, so `dbo_GI3_INTERVENTION.GI3_D_CLOT_INTRVT = '>2021-05-01'`

I only know how to count the number of time the certain value appear, but I don't know how to do the division.

This is what I got:

```
SELECT count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.gi3_intervention.gi3_n_intrvt WHERE dbo.gi3_intervention.GI3_C_TYPE_INTRVT = '08' and  dbo.gi3_intervention.GI3_D_CLOT_INTRVT >= Convert(datetime, '2021-05-01' ) * 100
FROM dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site
WHERE dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site.gi3_c_sous_sujt_note = 'Etud tech Renseig add'
```

Comment: just divide it normally `count(something) / number`

Comment: I don't know how to write the second part

Comment: In your question it doesn't seem the relation between tables is relevant. In this case you could just add the denominator to a variable and then proceed with the query. But this sounds strange. A little example of data, with only the relevant columns filled, and the expected result would really help to get the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can do this just as the ratio of two subqueries.  But, because you don't mention the database, I'll do the calculations in the `FROM` clause

```
select nias.cnt * 100.0 / gni.cnt
from (select count(*) as cnt
      from dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site nias
      where nias.gi3_c_sous_sujt_note = 'Etud tech Renseig add'
     ) nias cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from dbo.gi3_intervention.gi3_n_intrvt gni
      where gni.GI3_C_TYPE_INTRVT = '08' and  
            gni.GI3_D_CLOT_INTRVT >= Convert(datetime, '2021-05-01')
     ) gni;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site) * 100
FROM dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site
WHERE dbo.gi3_note_intervention_appr_site.gi3_c_sous_sujt_note = 'Etud tech Renseig add'
```

Comment: Thanks.. but it should be divided by the number of interventions... it's a second table. You omitted the second part of my question!

Comment: it's because it's not clear from your question what's the connection between the "values" and "interventions", there is not enough information in your question

Comment: you can see in the pictures i posted. there's values in every intervention. I just want the total values named "etud tech renseig add" divided by the total number of interventions that are closed since 01 may 2021. I even named everything about the "interventions"